# Connect android app with FRAPI

Tags: android, virtualhost, frapi

i have FRAPI in local and it works, i create a action and is ok!
but now if i try to consume this action with my android app, i try:

```
http://api.frapi/getusertype.json?user=122312
```

but not works

if i try

```
http://192.168.1.46/frapi/src/frapi/public/getusertype.json?user=122312
```

i have this error:

API Encountered some errors..

same if i try to connect with my smartphone with browser.
I try to change same attribute in my virtual server but still not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved!.. i access in hosts file, with (Hosts Editor app),  in my device and i add 192.168.1.46 api.frapi...now all works